# Why shrinkwrap not working on my mesh

Tags: modifiers

I added a normal cube and subdivided and added sub sub modifier. I want to shrinkwrap on the mesh but its not working on my object. I tried project in that all options but fails to shrinkwrap.

Whats I am doing wrong that I cannot achieve shrinkwrap on the mesh.

Any suggestion or help? Thanks

[image]

[image]

**scaling to x axis mesh getting distrub**

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apply scale (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> -> Scale) for target model:

[image]

Comment: read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data

Comment: Next time i think so i will never forget to apply scale. Thanks

Comment: One problem arise when i scale in x axis to cube its getting stuck to the edges. image added in question

Comment: @cegaton the above answer of crantisz work but when i scale in x axis mesh get disturb image added in question

Comment: @atek please ask new questions as a new post.